# Что означает строчка volumes: elasticsearch: null

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Подскажите что значит

```
volumes:
  elasticsearch: null
```

в данном docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  elasticsearch: null
services:
 composer:
image: 'composer:latest'
volumes:
  - '.:/app'
command: 'true'
elasticsearch:
build: ./docker/elasticsearch
volumes:
  - 'elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
environment:
  - cluster.name=portmone
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
ports:
  - '9200:9200'
  - '9300:9300'
```

Answer (score 1):

Та ничего особенного. Ключ **volumes** на верхнем уровне описывает хранилище и способ его создания. Если ничего не указано, что в данном случае равносильно указанию **null**, используется драйвер (движок) по-умолчанию "**local**". Но туда также можно передать расширенные параметры такие как:

- driver - другой драйвер для создания хранилища
- driver_opts - дополнительные параметры необходимые драйверу
- external - булево значение которое говорит что хранилище будет создано кем-то другим и создавать его не надо
- labels - метадата для хранилища
- name - другое имя для хранилища